# Python logging wont shutdown

Tags: python, logging

I have been learning the python logging module but have been having problems getting the logging to shutdown after it's done. Here is an example -

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
            fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            )
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(handler)

log.info('log file is open')  
logging.shutdown()
log.info('log file should be closed')
```

But the module is stilling logging after the logging.shutdown() as the log file looks like this -

```
# cat test.log
2014-07-17 19:39:35 INFO: log file is open
2014-07-17 19:39:35 INFO: log file should be closed
```

According to the documentation this command should "perform an orderly shutdown by flushing and closing all handlers". Should I be doing something else to close the log file ?

Comment: I can imagine that `shutdown()` indeed flushes data and closes handlers, but a subsequent `info()` call re-initializes them, using the same settings. Nobody promises that `shutdown()` prevents further logging; it only promises that it's safe to exit the process afterwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I found that the file handler for logging is not completely going away by using shutdown(). The best way seems to be to manually remove the file handler -

```
def main():
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
                    fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
                    )
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)

    log.info('-------Start--------')
    log.info('this function is doing something')
    log.info('this function is finished')
    log.removeHandler(fh) <--------------------------Add this line
    del log,fh
```

Comment: Naive reaction, but spontaneously I thought "what's the point then?" @9000 's comment on OP question clarifies where my intuition was wrong about the aim of `shutdown`. Resetting logging is not as simple as I thought...

Answer (score 8):

The [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown) for `shutdown` specifies that:

> This should be called at application exit and no further use of the
>   logging system should be made after this call.

It does not mean that the logger object **cannot** be used afterwards. After calling `shutdown`, simply don't try to log anything else using that logger object and that should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same probleme with the creation of a new logger with every call of the function. A solution that i found is to clear all handlers after executing the code

```
log.handlers.clear()
```

Don't know if it is the correct way but it works for me.

Comment: Yeah I tried something similar, setting handlers to an empty array since handlers is just a list. `log.handlers = []`. Both options worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem while writing a tKinter application. I had extensive logging as various controls were being used and every time I (for instance) pressed a certain button multiple times consecutively, the number of times a line was logged was equal to the number of times I pressed the button consecutively.

I added: `log.handlers.clear()` at the end of main() and it cleared the issue up.