# Python logging: how to delete a handler from all loggers?

Tags: python, logging, contextmanager

I created a context manager, with a specific logging handler, that the user can add to the loggers of its choice.

Here's the context code:

```py
# module mycontext.py
import logging

class myContext(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        # Create a specific loghandler:
        logformat = logging.Formatter()
        self.loghandler = logging.FileHandler('mycontext.log')
        self.loghandler.setFormatter(logformat)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, etype, evalue, tb):
        self.loghandler.close()
        # Now remove that handler everywhere
        # ...?
```

Here's an example usage:

```py
# Main application
from mycontext import myContext
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

with myContext() as ctxt:
    # mycontext gives the possibility to log messages to it: 
    logger.addHandler(ctxt.loghandler)
    
    pass
```

Now that the context exited, how do I ensure ctxt.loghandler has been removed from all loggers?

#### Current cumbersome solutions

1. First, I could of course wrap all code inside the `with` in a `try...finally`, but that's annoying not to take advantage of my context manager...
2. Naturally, just `del self.loghandler` in `__exit__` does not remove the actual object from all handlers lists.
3. As shown in ["logging won't shutdown"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24816456/4614641), `logging.shutdown(self.loghandler)` wouldn't work.
4. My *current working solution* is to iterate over all loggers:

```py
    def __exit__(self, etype, evalue, tb):
        self.loghandler.close()
        logging.root.removeHandler(self.loghandler)
        for logname, logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.items():
            logger.removeHandler(self.loghandler)
```

Isn't there a more efficient solution? Like an handler attribute refering to the associated loggers?

Answer (score 0):

You might try deleting all handlers this way - [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57176860/how-to-cleanly-start-logging-multiple-times-by-removing-all-handlers-with-remov/65439284#65439284):

```py
    def __exit__(self, etype, evalue, tb):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        while logger.hasHandlers():
            logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])
```